# How to upload a file to database on demand basis when it is already running on daily basis using task scheduler

Tags: php

I have below code which is scheduled to run daily at midnight using task scheduler. First my code is connecting to the database (function __construct),then it comparing he files which are in my logs folder and files which are already uploaded(function uploadLogs), then function uploadLog is uploading the file to the database which are not uploaded.The file which is uploaded is written a file in order to duplicate data(function updateRegistery).

Now when the file is uploaded once, then it can't be uploaded again, since the name is already written in the registry file. However I want to run it on daily basis. I really cant think of a way to do that. Can someone please help me with the coding.

My code:

```html
<?php

class logAgent
{
    const CONFIG_FILENAME = "data_config.ini";
    
    private $_dbConn;
    private $_config;
    
    
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->_loadConfig();
        
        
        $this->_dbConn = oci_connect($this->_config['db_usrnm'],
            $this->_config['db_pwd'],
            $this->_config['hostnm_sid']);
    }
    
   public function uploadLogs(){
        
        //Comparison of all the files present in the logs directory and all the files which has been already uploaded
        $f = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], 'r');
        $contents = [];
        while (FALSE !== ($row = fgetcsv($f, 1000, $this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator']))){
            $contents[] = $row[0];
        }
  $files = array_map('basename',glob($this->_config['logspath'] . $this->_config['fileextension'],GLOB_BRACE));
        $result = array_diff($files, $contents);
        foreach($result as $r){
            $this->uploadLog($r);
        }
    }
    
    
    private function _loadConfig()
    {
        // Loads config
        $path = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . self::CONFIG_FILENAME;
        $this->_config = parse_ini_file($path) ;
    }
    
    public function uploadLog($filename) {
        
        //Uploads file to database
        $filename = trim($this->_config['logspath'] . trim($filename));
        
        if(file_exists($filename)){
            $myfile = fopen($filename, "r");
            while(!feof($myfile)) {
                $content= fgets($myfile);
                $carray=explode($this->_config['logFomatDelimiter'],$content);

                list($REQUEST_TIME, $HOSTNAME, $IP_ADDRESS, $WORKFLOW_NAME, $USERID, $EVENT_MESSAGE , $OPTIONAL_DETAILS , $SESSION_COOKIES)=$carray;
    
    $data = array_map(function($v) { return explode('=',trim($v));},explode(';',substr($carray[6],strpos($carray[6],'=')+1)));
    foreach ($data as $datum) {
     if ($datum[0] == 'TANID') {
      $SESSION_COOKIES= $datum[0] . "=" . $datum[1];
      break;
     }
    }
                $statement = "INSERT INTO AUTH_LOGS(REQUEST_TIME, HOSTNAME, IP_ADDRESS, WORKFLOW_NAME, USERID, EVENT_MESSAGE , OPTIONAL_DETAILS , SESSION_COOKIES) 
                 values(to_date(:REQUEST_TIME, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS'), :HOSTNAME, :IP_ADDRESS, :WORKFLOW_NAME , :USERID ,:EVENT_MESSAGE ,
     :OPTIONAL_DETAILS, :SESSION_COOKIES)";
                
                //Preparing an Oracle statement for execution
                $compiled = oci_parse($this->_dbConn, $statement);
                
                //binding values to named parameters
    oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':REQUEST_TIME', $REQUEST_TIME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':HOSTNAME', $HOSTNAME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':IP_ADDRESS', $IP_ADDRESS);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled,':WORKFLOW_NAME', $WORKFLOW_NAME);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':USERID', $USERID);
    $EVENT_MESSAGE = str_replace('"', '', $EVENT_MESSAGE);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':EVENT_MESSAGE', $EVENT_MESSAGE);
    $OPTIONAL_DETAILS = str_replace('"', '', $OPTIONAL_DETAILS);
                oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':OPTIONAL_DETAILS', $OPTIONAL_DETAILS);
    $SESSION_COOKIES = str_replace(')"', '', $SESSION_COOKIES);
    oci_bind_by_name($compiled, ':SESSION_COOKIES', $SESSION_COOKIES);
                
              
                //Executing statement
                oci_execute($compiled, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);
            }
            //closing the file
            fclose($myfile);
            $this->updateRegistry($filename);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else{
            throw new Exception("File doesnot exist");
        }
    } 
    
    public function sendEmail(Exception $e){
        
        $sent = mail($this->_config['recipients'], $this->_config['notificationSubject'], $e);
    }
    
    public function updateRegistry($filename)
    {
        
        $uploadedfilename = fopen($this->_config['uploadedRegistry'], "a");
        fwrite($uploadedfilename, basename($filename . date($this->_config['filenameTimeSeparator'] . 'Ymdhi', time())) . PHP_EOL);
    } 
}

try {
    $logAgent = new logAgent();
    $logAgent->uploadLogs();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    $logAgent->sendEmail($e);
}
?>
```

Comment: You are already running this script on a daily basis, you said it runs every day at midnight

Comment: If you want to run it on an ADHOC basis, any time you feel like it, then just run it from a terminal

Comment: Or do you mean you want it to run for one specific file?

Comment: yeah i am running it on daily basis. But i want to run it as demand  basis too. I know i can run the scheduler anytime. But my problem is, once i run the task, it will write the filename in the registry, so next time when i run, it wont upload the file.i want to resolve that issue.Kindly, See my updateRegistry() function

Comment: How about this, put this in a batch/cmd file and the first thing the bath file does is tell Apache(I assume) to switch the log file. Then you just ignore the latest log file as that will be the open one

Comment: i get it but i am still not clear. Can you please explain a bit more

Comment: Where is the decision made whether to upload or not? That said, please format your code consistently according to PSR standards. It makes it easier to read and spot errors.